# Azure Logic Apps: how to run Powershell script or Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-logic-apps, azure-cli

I'm building my Azure Logic Apps worklow which is supposed to check some conditions and run following Powershell:

```
Stop-AzureWebsiteJob -Name MyWebsite -JobName MyWebJob
Start-AzureWebsiteJob -Name MyWebsite -JobName MyWebJob -JobType Continuous
```

The question is: what's the easiest way to invoke such script in Azure Logic Apps? It seems like there's no built in block/connector for Powershell so I'd like to know what are the possibilites. Or perhaps it might be easier to run az CLI command with similar operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually nowdays Azure provide this option, without creating runbooks and automation accounts. It is still in preview mode, but seems to be working !

[image]

Comment: This solution appears to require a paid license from a 3rd party, Ultima. See: [ms documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/iaconnectdynamiccode/)

Answer (score 11):

Finally I ended up with a solution which takes advantage of **Azure Automation**. From Azure Portal we can create new Resource typing in `Automation`:

[image]

Once the resource is created we can add new **Runbook** under runbooks tab:

[image]

Runbook can run Powershell [Workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-powershell-workflow) and get authorized using `AzureRunAsConnection` option (details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/manage-runas-account)). My sample Powershell which is supposed to restart WebJob an specific App Service looks like below:

```
Workflow RestartMyWebJob
{
    $Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
    Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint

    $AzureContext = Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID

    $Apiversion = "2015-08-01"
    $ResourceGroupName = 'My-Resource-Group-Name'
    $ResourceName = 'My-Resource-Group-Name/My-AppService--WebJob-Name'


    Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/ContinuousWebJobs -ResourceName $ResourceName -Action stop -ApiVersion $Apiversion -Force
    Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/ContinuousWebJobs -ResourceName $ResourceName -Action start -ApiVersion $Apiversion -Force
}
```

Having this Workflow setup we can run it from **Azure Logic Apps** by adding new block to our logic.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Currently, azure logic seems not support to run powershell and cli script, here is [a voice in azure feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/33913552-run-a-powershell-code-within-a-logic-app-action), you could vote it.

**Workaround**:

If you want to start and stop the webjob, you can call the [Kudu WebJobs API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#start-a-continuous-job) in the logic app.

You can follow the steps below.

1.Run the powershell command locally to generate the Authorization token of your web app.

```
$creds = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName joywebapp -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName joywebapp2/publishingcredentials -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
$username = $creds.Properties.PublishingUserName
$password = $creds.Properties.PublishingPassword
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))
```

The `$base64AuthInfo` is what we need, it should be like `JGpveXdlYmFwcDI6NnJxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxzRktSdXlUcU5acUUzdFhNb05j`.

The token will never be changed except you `reset the publish profile`, so you just need to do this step once.

2.In the logic app, specific the Method, URI, Headers(The header should be like
 `Authorization: Basic JGpveXdlYmFwcDI6NnJxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxzRktSdXlUcU5acUUzdFhNb05j`, **note** use space to separate the `Basic` and token), for example , I start a triggered webjob in my web app.

[image]

Triggered result:

[image]

So you just need to follow the steps above, for your issue, refer to the APIS:

1. [Start a continuous job](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#start-a-continuous-job)
2. [Stop a continuous job](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#stop-a-continuous-job)

Comment: In the meantime I've used Azure Automation and Runbooks however your answer is a great alternative and definitely needs to be accepted, thanks a lot !

Comment: @mickl Glad to know it is helpful.;-)

Answer (score 4):

Create an Azure Function with an http trigger with Powershell as the function language (or any other supported language). Then you call the Function easily in the Logic app by calling an Http endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have your PowerShell code run in an Azure Container Instance supporting PowerShell and create an new Container Group from the Logic App workflow.