# How to schedule deploying an ARM template?

Tags: azure, templates

I have an ARM template which I can run as a custom deployment in the Azure portal. How do I get this to run automatically on a schedule? I'm guessing I can do it with an automation account, but I did not find anything in there about deploying ARM templates.

Answer (score 1):

You have two (2) options:

- Logic App
- Runbook Automation

There is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53414671/azure-logic-apps-how-to-run-powershell-script-or-azure-cli) that shows how to implement this using either solutions.